# Select row position in filtered and ordered row list PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I got this query,

```
SELECT s.pos
  FROM (SELECT t.guild_id, t.user_id
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.reputation DESC) AS pos
    FROM users t) s
WHERE (s.guild_id, s.user_id) = ($2, $3)
```

that gets a user's "rank" in a guild, but I want to filter the results by entries that are in an array of `t.user_id` values (like `{'1', '64', '83'}`) and have this affect the resulting `pos` value. I found `FILTER` and `WITHIN GROUP`, but I'm not sure how to fit one of those into this query. How would I do that?

Here's the full table if that helps at all:

```
                        Table "public.users"
   Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 guild_id   | character varying(20) |           | not null | 
 user_id    | character varying(20) |           | not null | 
 reputation | real                  |           | not null | 0
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (guild_id, user_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not select on those first?

```
WITH UsersWeCareAbout AS (
  SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.user_id = ANY(subgroup_array)
), RepUsers AS (
  SELECT t.guild_id, t.user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.reputation DESC) AS pos
  FROM UsersWeCareAbout t
) SELECT s.pos FROM RepUsers s WHERE (s.guild_id, s.user_id) = ($2, $3)
```

(untested if only because I didn't really have enough context to test with)

Comment: Or actually I found a problem with it. the first select should be `(u.guild_id, u.user_id)` and the last one should be `s.user_id`. but whenever I try to put the any into the `($2, ANY($1))` it gives a syntax error